# Подключение классов

Tags: c++, классы

C++, Visual Studio 2013 
Как правильно подключать классы, если имеется следующая структура:
Файл Base.h:

```
class base{};
```

Файл Child1.h:

```
#include "base.h"
class Child : public base
{
}
```

Файл Child2.h:

```
#include "base.h"
class Child2 : public base
```

Файл Main.h:

```
#include "Child.h"
#include "Child2.h"
```

При таком включении получаю ошибку линковки: переопределение класса base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас в h файлах отсутствует защита от двойного включения. Самый простой способ - добавить `#pragma once` в самый верх каждого .h файла или сделать по старинке - завернуть в охранный "гуард"

```
#ifndef _FILENAME_H_
#define _FILENAME_H_
// тут код
#endif
```

`_FILENAME_H_` - должно быть уникально для каждого файла, поэтому, обычно оно совпадает с именем файла. Этот способ работает на практически всех доступных компиляторах с/с++. pragma once может не работать на старых компиляторах.

Comment: `на практически всех` ... встречали случаи, где не работало?

Comment: да, я пользовался c комилятором, в котором не было define.  Просто не было. Компилятор был по хитрые контроллеры, сейчас даже не вспомню. Автор вопроса вряд ли столкнется с подобным, но мало чего ...

Comment: В таком случае это не может называться `c компилятором` в полной мере. Это просто какая-то поделка. И кстати, вопрос ТС по `c++`.

Comment: я вкурсе, что вопрос по с++. А подделкой приходилось пользоваться, так как другого не было. А писать код прям в кодах мне не хотелось. Правда потом был прикручен препроцессор и все работало так как хотелось (да, если сильно быть педантом, обработка #ifdef - это работа препроцессора, а не компилятора. И как следствие ниодин правильный компилятор не поддерживает.  Но современные компиляторы это скрывают и делают препроцессирование самостоятельно).

Comment: Понятно, что это работа препроцессора, но препроцессорные директивы тем не менее описаны в Стандарте по языку. И я бы отнес это к базовой части того, что реализация должна уметь. Иначе можно придумать и компиляторы, которые, скажем, не имеют оператора `if`. Но назвать **такое** компилятором си, язык не поворачивается.

Comment: можно все. можно и без if писать код. Пока это приносит деньги и\или удовольствие.

Answer (score -2):

в первой строкой в хедере

```
pragma once
```

Comment: Это уже есть в другом ответе.